# Efficiently insert numbers - NumPy / Python

Tags: python, numpy

Returns a new vector where every element is separated by 4 consecutive zeros. Trying to achieve [4,2,1] --> [4,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1]

```
def zero_insert(x): 
    y = np.zeros((5*(len(x)-1))+1, dtype=np.int)
    for i in range(len(x)):
         y[5*i] = x[i]
    return y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize and assign -

```
x = np.asarray(x) # convert to array
n = 4             # number of zeros to be inserted
N = n+1
out = np.zeros((len(x)-1)*N+1,dtype=x.dtype)
out[::N] = x
```

Comment: I'm getting the error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'"

Comment: @NickDuddy Needed an array there as input. Check out the edits please.

Comment: @NickDuddy So, did the posted solution work for you?

Comment: I get this error when I run "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'"

Comment: @NickDuddy Did you try out the edit in which I suggested using `x = np.asarray(x)` at the start?

Comment: I made an error when implementing. It did work in the end.